# Dock throwing NSInvalidArgumentException trying to start

Tags: macos, finder, dock, plist

Yesterday I noticed that I could no longer <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, minimize/maximize windows and that the Dock was missing. I've tried numerous things to resolve it:

- [rebooting](http://media.giphy.com/media/F7yLXA5fJ5sLC/giphy.gif)
- reseting PRAM
- killing Dock with `killall -KILL Dock`

That last one should restart the process, but it didn't appear to initially:

```
$ killall -KILL Dock
No matching processes belonging to you were found
$ ps -ef|grep -i Dock
  501  2145   826   0  7:50AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i Dock
```

I opened up the Activity Monitor and noticed that it was repeatedly *trying* to restart the process:

[image]

When I tried to restart it manually I noticed that a `NSInvalidArgumentException` was being thrown:

```
$ /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
2015-01-27 07:30:34.441 Dock[1126:38505] -[__NSCFNumber stringByExpandingTildeInPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x537
2015-01-27 07:30:34.442 Dock[1126:38505] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber stringByExpandingTildeInPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x537'
*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d6ec64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff819096de objc_exception_throw + 43
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d6ef6bd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d636a84 ___forwarding___ + 1028
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d6365f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
  5   Dock                                0x000000010907feca Dock + 61130
  6   Dock                                0x000000010907fd75 Dock + 60789
  7   Dock                                0x000000010907f780 Dock + 59264
  8   Dock                                0x000000010907cc70 Dock + 48240
  9   Dock                                0x000000010907be54 Dock + 44628
  10  Dock                                0x000000010907696c Dock + 22892
  11  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff837e95c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions? I miss my dock and my keyboard shortcuts...

Comment: I guess you could try `kill -9`?

Comment: Safe mode? single user mode? Permissions repair?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Still no dice with safe/single user/verbose mode or permissions repair.

Comment: Remove preference files related to the Dock?

Comment: Thanks, Ashley. I tried removing `com.apple.dock*` and restarting. Still have the same problem :(

Comment: If you set up another user account (for testing), does the Dock function OK there?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and fixed it by removing `desktoppicture.db`:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db
```

Then Dock started automatically.

Comment: Deleting most of the Dock preference files in ~/Library/Preferences is also worth a shot.

Comment: @benwiggy I did that also, but it didn't help on its own at least

Comment: @felixbade Im sorry if this is weird but I love you so much!!! Thank you my computer has been broken all week and this fixed it